# math function with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to using jQuery do some basic math functions.

Step 1. User enter Gross weight, and Tare weight, my function auto generate Net weight, which is Gross weight minus Tare weight.(This step works)

Step 2. User enter Price per pound, my function use Price per pound times Net weight to calculate total cost.

So far my code looks like this, it returns the net weight but does not return the total cost:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       $(".sub").focusout(function() {
         $("#net").html('');
         var gross = $("#gross").val();
         var tare = $("#tare").val();
         var net = gross-tare;
         $("#net").html(Math.round(net*1000)/1000);
        });
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
       $(".sub1").focusout(function() {
         $("#total").html('');
         var net = $("#net").val();
         var ppp = $("#ppp").val();
         var total = net*ppp;
         $("#total").html(Math.round(total*1000)/1000);
        });
    }); 

  </script>
```

And the HTML:

```
   <input type='number' name='gross' id=gross class=sub>
   <input type='number' name='tare' id=tare class=sub>
   <p id=net name='net'></p>
   <input type="number" id=ppp name="ppp" class=sub1/>
   <p id=total name='total'></p>
```

Forgive me if I am making stupid mistakes as I barely know jQuery, this is just one requirement for my project that I am working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few minor things:

-`id=gross` should have quotes `id='gross'`

-`$("#net").val();` net doesn't have a value, its a `p`, so use `text()`

-you'll want to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sub").focusout(function () {
        $("#net").html('');
        var gross = $("#gross").val();
        var tare = $("#tare").val();
        var net = gross - tare;
        $("#net").html(Math.round(net * 1000) / 1000);
    });

    $(".sub1").focusout(function () {
        $("#total").html('');
        var net = parseInt($("#net").text());
        var ppp = parseInt($("#ppp").val());
        var total = net * ppp;
        $("#total").html(Math.round(total * 1000) / 1000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' name='gross' id='gross' class='sub'/>
<input type='number' name='tare' id='tare' class='sub'/>
<p id='net' name='net' class='sub1'></p>
<input type="text" id='ppp' name="ppp" class='sub1'/>
<p id='total' name='total'></p>
```

Comment: "you'll want to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`" in most instances I recommend using the unary `+` operator to cast to a `Number` instead of `parseFloat`. It's more concise too: `+$('#gross').val()`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the class names/ ids or other attributes in quotes. They are parsed wrongly by the browser. Check using "firebug" or "inspect element".

**Problem in your code:** You are using '$("#net").val()', but `$.val()` works only on input fields but `#net` is a `<p>` tag, so get its text using `$.html()`.

Your code should be like this

**HTML:**

```
<input type='number' name='gross' id=gross class="sub">
<input type='number' name='tare' id=tare class="sub">
<p id="net" name='net'></p>
<input type="number" id="ppp" name="ppp" class="sub1"/>
<p id="total" name='total'></p>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".sub").focusout(function() {
      $("#net").html('');
      var gross = $("#gross").val();
      var tare = $("#tare").val();
      var net = gross-tare;
      $("#net").html(Math.round(net*1000)/1000);
   });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".sub1").focusout(function() {
     $("#total").html('');
     var net = parseFloat($("#net").html());
     var ppp = parseFloat($("#ppp").val());
     var total = net*ppp;
     $("#total").html(parseFloat(total));
   });
});
```

[image]